# Number of created blocks/threads and of occupied memory when CUDA cufftExecC2C is invoked

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I'm using cuFFT functions in my program. I'm using Tesla k20 card. My signal size is 16384.

How many number of blocks and threads will be created and how much memory will be consumed on the GPU when cufftExecC2C is called?

Comment: Your title asked about memory and the body asks about execution parameters. Which is it that you want to know?

Comment: For the execution parameters, you can use [nvprof](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvprof-overview) to answer this yourself.  `nvprof --print-gpu-trace <your-executable>`.

Comment: @talonmies I want to know about both memory and execution parameters..

Answer (score 3):

As @harrism indicated, you can use [nvprof](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvprof-overview) to discover the execution parameters.

```
nvprof --print-gpu-trace <your-executable>
```

For the memory, you could use an observational method as well, such as using `nvidia-smi` to query GPU memory usage while your application is running, or use one of the CUDA API calls like [cudaMemGetInfo](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gd5d6772f4b2f3355078ecd6059e6aa74) to query memory while your FFT is running.

In CUDA 5.5, a new set of CUFFT API calls are introduced to help with estimating memory needs as well.  The relevant API calls are:

```
cufftEstimate1d(…)
cufftEstimate2d(…)
cufftEstimate3d(…)
cufftEstimateMany(…)
```

These calls will return an estimated memory usage size for the proposed transform type and size.

Refer to the CUDA 5.5 RC documentation in (e.g. for a linux cuda 5.5 RC install):

> /usr/local/cuda/doc/pdf/CUFFT_Library.pdf

In particular section 3.4 "CUFFT Estimated Size of Work Area"

You can get a more accurate estimate of the size if you have a plan developed, using the following CUDA 5.5 CUFFT API `cufftGetSize...` calls analogous to the estimate calls.  Refer to section 3.5 of the aforementioned doc for details.